# uiactivityviewcontroller from toolbar

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

I´m trying to use the following code in my app to get the uiactivityviewcontroller, and it works if I set up a round rect button, but not with a UIBarButtonItem? Am I missing something really simple here?

```
- (IBAction)shareIt:(id)sender {
    NSArray *activityItems;

    activityItems = @[_textView.text];


    UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
    [self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint to see if the method is even called.

Comment: Ok, it´s not being called. Maybe because I´m using the viewcontroller as a result of several rows in tableviewcontroller.

Comment: You're sure you set the action of the barButtonItem correctly in IB/code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing (read: I'm sure) that this is happening because you didn't hook up the action to the `barButtonItem` correctly in code. If you are making it in code, you can use this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *bBI = ...; //get it
[bBI setTarget:self];
[bBI setAction:@selector(shareIt:)];
```

Comment: turns out that the gesturerecognizer interfered with the toolbar.